# How to view the previous commits of a repo?

Tags: git

I am reading an open source library with >1000 commits. I want to read the repository at different commits. I dont want to reset anything either locally or remotely. What are the commands that are needed for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to review previous commits, then `git log --oneline` would probably all what you need.

If you then want to revert to a particular commit, say A, then

```
git checkout -f A -- .
```

Comment: And then how do I switch the code to that commit ? I want to have the local repo exactly like it was on that commit and then be able to switch again and again.

Comment: then you need to revert to that specific commit - see edit

Comment: _revert_ is a bad choice of words, as that means something else in git.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to read the repository at different commits.

The easiest and cleanest way to do this is to use a diff tool in your IDE (e.g. IntelliJ, Eclipse) or Git tool (e.g. SourceTree).  This will allow you to compare any two commits in a branch.

If you really need to do some serious poking around at previous commits, then I would recommend that you checkout the branch at a previous commit via:

```
git checkout <sha1>
```

where `<sha1>` is the hash of the commit you want to inspect.  When you are finished looking around, to return to the regular branch just use:

```
git checkout yourBranch
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git log                     # see the commits and copy hash you want to go
$ git checkout <commit-hash>  # checkout to that commit

$ git checkout <branch-name>  # back to the HEAD of branch
```